# How to make a bootstrap dropdown parent link clickable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, hyperlink, bootstrap-4, dropdown, parent

A parent link of a bootstrap dropdown isn't clickable by default so the link isn't working.

This is the html code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
<a id="item7" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/mylink">MyLink</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="submenuitem">
        <a href="//item-1">item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="submenuitem">
        <a href="/item-2">item 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want /myLink to clickable. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

Add this code to you page and parent links will work:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.dropdown > a').click(function(){
        location.href = this.href;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the easiest way to do it in bootstrap 4 is by deleting the "data-toggle" attribute from the parent element!

Comment: If you remove data-toggle the menu dropdown doesn't work at all. At least not when I tested it.